# angularjs with other js library

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs project and I am trying to use a coverflow js library in that angularjs project to display images in coverflow style. Now the changes for this are simple. i.e. - add coverflow js and css in project and include them in main code and then simply copy paste the html for coverflow. Now I can not get this working in angularjs but it works very well without angularjs. My doubt is that coverflow js library is modifying the dom but angularjs is not letting it do somehow.

Now my question is how can I use a third party js library in an angularjs project.

Comment: Can you link what coverflow library you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to be wrapped with angularjs directive. Angularjs directive lets you control DOM, so that all 3rd party js can be function within the directive.

You can build one, or google with "angularjs coverflow directive". You may find one easily.

I find this, http://southdesign.de/blog/angular-coverflow.html, but haven't tested yet.

The challenge is how well we can wrap 3rd party js to AngularJS directive by exposing all necessary features as directive attributes. I was having the same issue with [ng-map](http://allenhwkim.tumblr.com/post/70986888283/google-map-as-the-simplest-way).

Please remember that all DOM manipulation happens in directive with AngularJS.